# Which android internet browser can download a specific file by clicking on a specific button?

Tags: applications, browser, internet, downloading

I'd like to see the four different graphical altitude profiles (original, 1st, 2nd and 3rd alternative) for my specific route with my personal profile (write something in the field "Profile") on my smartphone (Android 5.0) created with http://brouter.de/brouter-web/ and download it by clicking the GPX button.

I've tried following android apps (without success):

- Google Chrome
- Chrome Beta
- Firefox Beta
- CM Browser
- Ninesky Browser
- Opera
- Opera Mini
- Dolphin
- Photon Flash Player

Only with the Dolphin app I was able to paste by clicking in this field a text (the code from a customized profile for optimal route calculation which is saved on my smartphone), but clicking on the Download Button on GPX didn't work. I was asking why does the internet browser app not allows to click on the GPX text.

Summary:

- In the Dolphin app: insert of the code works, also the choice of the four alternatives perfectly works. But the download is impossible.
- Only with the Android app Opera I was able to download the GPX file, it really works! But here in this web browser I was not able to insert the customized brf profile text.

Is there an android app which can do both: write a code in the "Profile" field and click onto the "GPX" to download the calculated route?

Comment: Is this question not concerned like "Using your Android device"? How would you suggest me to improve this question?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your problem may not be with the browsers, but that Android doesn't have any app willing to support the specific download.

You could try downloading an app which has an option to support all downloads, such as [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop). It should then offer to open the GPX file when you click on it to download.

Comment: No, that's not true. With the android app "Opera" the download of the GPX file works. Because the GPX button has no URL (because the file is generated every time newly), you cannot use ES File Explorer for this webpage.

Comment: @laminin -- All that says to me is that Opera is already allowing you to download any file. ES File Explorer doesn't open web pages, but just provides a handler for opening arbitrary files. If you already have ES File Explorer installed and setup to handle any file, then this answer doesn't help you. If you don't, I would suggest you try it.

Comment: Yes, I already know it and I also like it as a download manager, but for this webpage it doesn't work.